# Realm findAll() some time empty?

Tags: android, realm

```
 AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override public void run() {
     if (isbackendLoad){   
     // Backend load  I must use syn retrofit because some reason.
     // saveResulttoRealm
     } else {
     final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
     RealmResults<RealmAnimal> realmAnimals =
     realm.where(RealmAnimal.class).equalTo("DogId",DogId,    Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
     }
   }
 });
```

In Animal I have DogId field. I check in realm browser, it have Animal with DogId but result is empty. This realm query without AsyncTask.execute work ok. The reason is AsyncTask.execute ?. But I must use the for Syn Retorfit, without it retrofit return null.
Some thread Ex: Async #1 return null, Aysnc other have result != null.

Comment: use findFirst method..instead of findAll.

Comment: Are you closing your Realm instances on your background threads? in `finally {` block

Comment: Thanks @TheFlash and @ EpicPandaForce . But I think my problems is I use realm query in AsyncTask.execute(). It can the reason ?

Comment: Did you close the realm instance every time in async task? Also, you have to ensure the transaction is committed before async task starts.

Comment: yes, I use realm.close and commit when it done. But not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get result in right time . exactly after the AsyncTask done . before this process will return null . check the return value in  `finally {` it will show you that your problem where happen .

Comment: Thanks @amir , But in my AsyncTask for many work, realm query is a part of it (it must done before other work). Can I use orther thread for realm query, but I will meet problems mutiple thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try for this

```
realm.where(RealmAnimal.class)
                .equalTo("DogId", DogId, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                .or()
                .contains("DogId", DogId, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                .findAll();
```

or else you might be having problem with the "DogId" since thats the column name, and must be same as defined in database table

Comment: Thank @Niroj Shr I find the problems may be the reason is I query in AsyncTask.execute().  But I need use it in AsyncTask with orther request sysn backend. It can work in AsysTask

Answer (score 0):

I solve that problems by create one thread for save and fetch from realm.

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
      if (isbackendLoad){   
     // Backend load  I must use syn retrofit because some reason.
     //handler.post(() -> saveResulttoRealm;
     } else {
      handler.post(new Runnable(){
       @Override public void run() {
     final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
     RealmResults<RealmAnimal> realmAnimals =
     realm.where(RealmAnimal.class).equalTo("DogId",DogId,    Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll(); 
     }
     });
   }
 });
```

Comment: Your Realm instance is never closed on your background thread. This is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you help me. I try close realm with realm close but it don't work. I am a newbie, you can give me example code to close it.

Comment: I'd have to know more of your code to give a proper answer :) But here's an article for you that might help https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/basics-of-realm-a-guide-to-using-realm-1-2-0-634471c0fe8f

Comment: Thank @EpicPandaForce, Very useful documents :)